# jQuery set as active next or previous submenu

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

I'm working with this jSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vkuz8ra3/

And i need function which active next or previous link after click to div prev or div next.

I tried something like this but it does not work

```
$('.prev').click(function() {
  $('#links').children().prev().addClass('active');
    var index = $('#links').children().index('#links');
    $('#linksobsah').children().hide(500).eq(index).show(500);               
    $('#links').children().removeClass('active');
    $('#links').addClass('active'); 
});
```

How can i do that?

Comment: I tried the solution from Saksham but it not working :/ Someone can help me ? :/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to maintain a global variable and use that to show or hide the sub menu

Suppose you have `li`s with class `link1`, `link2`..

And menus with class 'menu menu1 active`,`menu menu2` ...(notice that first is active)

Maintain a global counter as

```
var counter = 0;
```

Your function should be

```
$('.prev').click(function(){
    $('menu.active').removeClass('active');
    counter--;
    $('.menu' + counter % $('menu').length).addClass('active');
});
```

Similarly for next

```
$('.next').click(function(){
    $('menu.active').removeClass('active');
    counter++;
    $('.menu' + counter % $('menu').length).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Hi. I can not make it running. I copied your code, tried to change some variables but still nothing. Im enclosing updated jsFiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/f7myg2yy/ Thank you for your time.